# Getting --lines-terminated-by to work in a mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Below is the code I use to create a tab delimited backup of my database.

```
mysqldump --user=**** --fields-enclosed-by=\" --lines-terminated-by="\n" --password=**** --host=localhost --tab=/path/to/folder ****
```

What I cannot get to work is this:

```
--lines-terminated-by="\n"
```

At the moment, if I have a TEXT column in my MySQL database, it outputs like this:

```
"1"    "A test post"    "This is an example of text on multiple lines.
\
As you can see this is how it places it in the txt file.
\
Blah blah blah"
"2"    "Another post"    "More text....."
```

This is what I'm trying to achive

```
"1"    "A test post"    "This is an example of text on multiple lines.\nAs you can see this is how it places it in the txt file.\nBlah blah blah"
"2"    "Another post"    "More text....."
```

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lines-terminated-by), `--lines-terminated-by=...` is supported when outputting using `--tab`. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

The output you get is consistent with [the documentation for `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html). Line breaks are prefixed with the default escape character, which is `\`. The `--lines-terminated-by` option refers to what character is used as record separator, not to how line breaks inside a field are represented.

There is no option to make the output look like you want directly from `mysqldump`, but you can post-process the files to get the results you need. For instance, you could filter the files with:

```
perl -pe 's/\\\n/\\n/'
```